# Hibernate fetch lazy loaded child list in sorted order

Tags: hibernate

I have a below HQL query

```
"select distinct p from Participant p left join fetch p.basketItemViewStates as bi where p.basket.id = ?1 order by p.lastName"
```

where `Participant` has child list of `BasketItemViewStates` and BasketItemViewStates further have a child with one to one relationship called

```
   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private BasketItem basketItem;
```

BasketItem has `sortOrder as a column`, i want that list which is fetched in join, should be sorted on the basis of that sortOrder.

Can anyone explain, how i can do it in above query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add  `, bi.sortOrder` at the end of your hql request :

```
select distinct p from Participant p left join fetch p.basketItemViewStates as bi where p.basket.id = ?1 order by p.lastName, bi.sortOrder
```

You can also use a sortedCollection of your child and implements the `Comparable` interface on your child Entity and specify to hibernate you want this collection sorted by natural order.

[Edit]
After editing your question, I think something like this should work :

```
select distinct p from Participant p left join fetch p.basketItemViewStates as bi left join bi.basketItem as bitem where p.basket.id = ?1 order by p.lastName, bitem.sortOrder
```

Comment: Oh I am sorry i specified the question wrong, actually BasketItemViewStates further have one to one relationship on BasketItem, which has the column sortOrder, on which i want to apply sortOrder